# Eclipse AsyncCallback failed

Tags: gwt, asynccallback, eclipse-oxygen

I'm new at this place, please excuse me if this question is a random question :)

So my problem is I Installed:

- Eclipse Oxygen
- Google Cloud Platform / App AppEngine
- MySqlConnector is in place

Evertime when I start my programm with right click -> Run As-> GWT Development Mode with Jetty eclipse is showing me some errors like "RPC Call failed etc."
My prof. said for the GWT login this is normal but how can I test all my other methods which I wrote with the AsyncCallback? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmSAu.png)

I hope someone could help me :/
I thank you in advance.

Comment: You should check the server log.

Comment: How can I check the Server log? Because it’s all on a local server. I use mamp for this.

Comment: The error code shows a 500 or 404 but the most common was the 500

Comment: 404 means not found, so you have a problem with your url or server configuration. 500 means you have successfully contacted the server but the server rans into an exception. That's the difference.

Comment: Thanks I finally fixed the problem, it couldn’t reach the jdbc driver, I put it to the lib folder and now it works :)

Comment: ok, that explains the 500.